# UITableViewDataSource Method can not be called, Even cursor doesn't get inside those methods on debugging

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c-blocks

This is My Class in which Methods for UITableViewDatasource are overrided to have data as 'Email' in Tableview in a single Cell using UITableViewCell as in code. but these methods don't get executed. Will anybody please help me to fix this isseu ?

import UIKit

var operationViewFlag: Int!

class HomeCellView: UITableViewCell
{

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn_tablecell_Delete: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn_tablecell_Edit: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_tablecell_Email: UILabel!
```

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{

```
@IBOutlet weak var TableView_Mainscreen: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_MainScreen_Title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btn_Mainscreen_Insert: UIButton!


var databasepath:String!
var arrayStudInfo:NSMutableArray!


// viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad()
{

    operationViewFlag=1

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    lbl_MainScreen_Title.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)
    btn_Mainscreen_Insert.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    btn_Mainscreen_Insert.layer.borderWidth = 1
    btn_Mainscreen_Insert.layer.borderColor = UIColor.brownColor().CGColor


    // Variable Intialization
    arrayStudInfo = NSMutableArray()


    // Process for Creating Opening Database
    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirpath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let docdir = dirpath[0] as String
    databasepath = docdir.stringByAppendingString("StudentDataManipulation.sqlite");

    if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasepath as String)
    {
        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasepath as String)
        if contactDB == nil
        {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
        if contactDB.open()
        {
            let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentData (Name TEXT, Phone TEXT, Email TEXT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL, Comment TEXT)"

            if !contactDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)
            {
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
            contactDB.close()
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
    }
}

//viewWillAppear
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    listAllData()
}

//didReceiveMemoryWarning
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Edit Method
@IBAction func btn_Edit_Clicked(sender: UIButton)
{
    operationViewFlag=2

    let updateView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PerformOperation") as! PerformOperation
    updateView.strEmail = arrayStudInfo[sender.tag]["Email"] as? String
    print("Email to pass = \(updateView.strEmail)")
    updateView.dictRecord = (arrayStudInfo[sender.tag] as! NSDictionary)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(updateView, animated: true)
}


// Delete Method
@IBAction func btn_Delete_Clicked(sender: UIButton)
{

    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasepath as String)
    let strDelete = arrayStudInfo[sender.tag]["Email"] as? String
    if contactDB.open()
    {
        let deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM StudentData WHERE Email='\(strDelete!)'"

        let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(deleteSQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
        if !result
        {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Deleted Record.")
            listAllData()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
    contactDB.close()
}



// List All Data
func listAllData()
{
    arrayStudInfo.removeAllObjects();
    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasepath as String)
    if contactDB.open()
    {
        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dirpath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let docdir = dirpath[0] as String
        databasepath = docdir.stringByAppendingString("StudentDataManipulation.sqlite");

        if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasepath as String)
        {
            let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasepath as String)
            if contactDB == nil
            {
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
            if contactDB.open()
            {
                let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentData (Name TEXT, Phone TEXT, Email TEXT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL, Comment TEXT)"
                if !contactDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)
                {
                    print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }
                let SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM StudentData"
                if let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB.executeQuery(SelectQuery, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
                {
                    while results?.next() == true
                    {
                        let dictRecord = results?.resultDictionary()
                        arrayStudInfo.insertObject(dictRecord!, atIndex: arrayStudInfo.count)
                        print("\nRESULT : \(results?.resultDictionary())")
                    }
                    TableView_Mainscreen.reloadData()
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Recored not found");
                }
                contactDB.close()
            }
            else
            {
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
        }
        contactDB.close()
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
}


// TableView Methods
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return arrayStudInfo.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellHome") as! HomeCellView
    Cell.lbl_tablecell_Email.text! = arrayStudInfo[(indexPath.row)]["Email"] as! String

    print("Your Email : \(Cell.lbl_tablecell_Email.text!)")

    Cell.btn_tablecell_Edit.tag=indexPath.row
    Cell.btn_tablecell_Delete.tag=indexPath.row
    Cell.btn_tablecell_Edit.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    Cell.btn_tablecell_Delete.layer.cornerRadius = 10


   // btn_Delete_Clicked
    Cell.btn_tablecell_Edit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.btn_Edit_Clicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    Cell.btn_tablecell_Delete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.btn_Delete_Clicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return Cell
}
```

}

Comment: Cannot find any line setting `dataSource` of `TableView_Mainscreen`.

Comment: Thank you Very Much its going fine....!

Answer (score 1):

Did you set delegate and data source to ViewController.

If you are using storyboard, you can control click your tableView to ViewController and set both delegate and data source.

If you want to do it in code, you can do this

```
TableView_Mainscreen.delegate = self
TableView_Mainscreen.datasource = self
```

Also you should be using lower camel case to name your variable.